# Catch a CrossOrigin access in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I need to know if a client tried accessing my endpoints that are not part of my whitelist domains. I wanted to throw server exception and return a JSON format message to the client for them to handle it gracefully.

I can't seem to get any clear answer on the Spring Boot docs on how to do this. Can anyone suggest the correct way to do this?

Comment: What is your whitelist domains?

Comment: Does it matter? Domains are localhost and 127.0.0.1 - Basically, I want the endpoints to be only accessible via a locally deployed app.

Comment: I do not care about the actual domain, i was referring to what you meant by domain.  So you mean the host section of a URL?

Comment: Yeah but again does it matter? I only need to catch the CrossOrigin exception / violation.

Comment: Yes it matters.   The word domain is so ambiguous and overly used that its almost meaningless unless the context is clarified.  So let me see if I have this straight, you have a requirement that the "host" section of the URL must be in a list that you have access to during runtime?

Comment: My question is more on handling the violation so that I can throw a better response. My code has this @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000"). I want to be able to handle requests that are "NOT" coming from the specified origin. My question is, how do I handle that?

Comment: Before cross origin request, a pre-flight call occurred. Did your system send/received any `http` request with `OPTION` method ?